# fetching countriesInShippingZones

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I'm trying to fetch the countries that I can ship to with shopify-buy.

as client.shop.fetchInfo() doesn't return that information I build my own query with the unoptimized version of the SDK to fetch the store information.

But any query with countriesInShippingZones always returns the error **"Error: No field of name "countriesInShippingZones" found on type "Shop" in schema"** (without that, it works)

here is an example of my query:

```
props.client.graphQLClient.query((root) => {
  root.add("shop", {}, (shop) => {
    shop.add("name");
    shop.add("currencyCode");
    shop.add("countriesInShippingZones");
  });
});
```